# Dismiss a viewController from 2 modal presentation to especific viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have next

[image: My storyBoard]

I want to ***dismiss my vc3 to the vc2*** the thing is that it was presented by the vc1 so when I do the dismissViewController it returns to VC1, on the navigation from vc1 to vc3 I never instantiates or show the Vc2

Any idea?

Comment: i think u can use rewind segue from vc3 to vc1, in the rewind method of vc1 then push the view from vc1 to vc2, then it will dismiss vc3 safely

Comment: I did just that you say, and it functions, but i don't know if it's the best solution. Thanks! @Tj3n

Comment: because u push from vc1 to vc3, the vc1 still are in the memory, so its not that u recreate the vc1, its just come back from vc3 with a notification to do some stuff, so im pretty sure theres no problem at all, there are many way to do this like block, delegate, notification, it might all just be the same :D
With this rewind solution u can pass your result data around very easily too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delegate method which gets called when you dismiss VC3,and so when the delegate passes to VC1 push VC2

Comment: the user will see the transition? or it's not notable for the eye

Comment: You will have to turn animation off while popping and pushing, that way he will not notice.

Comment: If i make a segue from vc3 to vc2 it is functional?

Comment: No,it will break the flow while popping the view controllers

Comment: The flow will be from vc3 to vc1 and from vc1 to vc2

Comment: I cant do a pop from vc3 to vc 1 and push vc2 because i need to send data from vc3 to vc2

Comment: Yes you can do that the above logic first pass data from vc3 to vc1 in delegate methods, and while pushing data from vc1 to vc2 pass that data

Comment: I did it because make a direct segue from vc3 to vc2 doesn't function, the thing is that it's naviation from vc3-vc1 and then vc1 to vc2 is not quickly like the user doesn't see the transition, I put the animation false in the delegate and the presentation from vc1 to vc2. Do you know what can I do

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];

// [navigationArray removeAllObjects];    // This is just for remove all view controller from navigation stack.
MyFansViewController *vc3 = [[MyFansViewController alloc] init];
[navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 2]; // You can pass your index here
[navigationArray addObject:vc3];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
```

I haven't tested but it will work after some modification